# How to convert a UTC Datetime to Local Datetime?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, datetime

I need to convert a utc datetime to a local datetime.

it should look something like this:

```
private DateTime localdate (DateTime UTC_DateTime)
{

DateTime local =  new DateTime();
local  = UTC_DateTime .....         ??? 

return local;

}
```

Thanks in advance for your Help!

Comment: Atleast Google before u ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

Do it like so:

```
private DateTime Localdate (DateTime utc_DateTime)
{

    DateTime local =  new DateTime();
    local  = utc_DateTime.ToLocalTime();

    return local;

 }
```

But the method itself is "a bit" redundant.
Just a recommendation: Try to respect the "Pascal-case convention" embraced by C# which states that method names are capitalized and that parameter names are not (amongst other things).

Answer (score 0):

use method `DateTime.ToLocalTime()`